# date-fns formats date incorrectly

Tags: javascript, date-format, date-fns

Using date-fns I am trying to format the following `yyyy/mm/dd`

```
2022-10-26
```

to

```
2022/26/10
```

Here is my code:

```
    const date = document.getElementById('date').value
    console.log('Date -> ', date) // date is correct here
    const formatDate = format(new Date(date), 'yyyy/dd/mm');
```

For 2022-10-26 date-fns outputs the following:

```
 2022/25/00
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here and how to correctly format the date as `yyyy/dd/mm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because according to the [date-fns documentation](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/format), `mm` is minutes with leading zeros. You need to use `MM` for months:

```
const formatDate = format(new Date(date), 'yyyy/dd/MM');
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the month problem. But I am still getting the wrong day. It is always the date before. That is, if I choose the 14th, it will come out as the 13th instead. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Most likely due to timezone differences.  I would assume one value is UTC and the other is not. Convert them both to the same timezone.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have to look into the timezones aspect but it shouldn't be too big a problem to fix.